# UISegmentedControl TintColor to Gradient Color

Tags: ios, swift, tintcolor

I am trying to set UIsegmentedControl tint color for the selected segment to gradient color and I am unable to do it

I am trying to follow this article https://www.bethedev.com/2019/02/set-gradient-tint-color-for-segmented.html

Trying to use this code:

```
segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white],for: UIControl.State.normal)
        segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white],for: UIControl.State.selected)  

fileprivate func updateGradientBackground() {
        let sortedViews = segmentedControl.subviews.sorted( by: { $0.frame.origin.x < $1.frame.origin.x } )
        for (_, view) in sortedViews.enumerated() {
//            let gradientImage = gradient(size: segmentedControl.frame.size, color: [UIColor.cyan,UIColor.blue])!
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "segmentedRectangle.png")!)
            view.tintColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }
```

I am expecting only one segment to be of the segmentedRectangle.png image color but it is displaying on the entire segmented control like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McsNf.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code, I put comments on relevant parts. Let me know if you need more explanation.

```
 let segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
       let view =  UISegmentedControl(items: ["Pounds", "Kilograms"])
        view.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        view.tintColor = .black
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40, height: 20)
        /// Gradient
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:  UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40, height: 20)
        let leftColor = UIColor.red
        let rightColor = UIColor.purple
        gradient.colors = [leftColor.cgColor, rightColor.cgColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        /// Create gradient image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradient.frame.size)
        gradient.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let segmentedControlImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        // Normal Image
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        let context:CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!;
        context.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
        context.fill(rect)
        let normalImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        /// Set segmentedControl image
        view.setBackgroundImage(normalImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        view.setBackgroundImage(segmentedControlImage, for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
        return view
    }()
```

**Usage:**
On your ViewDidLoad set navigationItem title view as your segmented control like so:-

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl
```

[image: Output]

I think with few modifications/custominization you can get want you want, Cheers :)

**StoryBoard/InterfaceBuilder**

Just call this inside your ViewDidLoad and pass your outlet name on the function call: -

```
   func configureSegementedControl(segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl) {
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        segmentedControl.tintColor = .black
        segmentedControl.backgroundColor = .white
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40, height: 20)
        /// Gradient
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:  UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40, height: 20)
        let leftColor = UIColor.red
        let rightColor = UIColor.purple
        gradient.colors = [leftColor.cgColor, rightColor.cgColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        /// Create gradient image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradient.frame.size)
        gradient.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let segmentedControlImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        // Normal Image
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        let context:CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!;
        context.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
        context.fill(rect)
        let normalImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        /// Set segmentedControl image
        segmentedControl.setBackgroundImage(normalImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
        segmentedControl.setBackgroundImage(segmentedControlImage, for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
    }
```

Comment: thank you Mussa, can i call everything in viewDidLoad() ?

Comment: Yes, I have added a way to call it on the last part of the code.  On your ViewDidLoad if your VC is embedded in navigationController set it like this:-
 self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl

Comment: @KrisRaduhaSt if this solved your issue please don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer :)

Comment: Mussa Really appreciate immensely your help, one last question: i already have an existing @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl! how do i connect this to the code you wrote? and changing segment colors upon selection?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EVgs6vn5
        I am almost there but not sure where to map the View in the last two lines.

Comment: Aww because I created mine programmatically that's why I had to do the let segmentedControl... {}() for your case since you are using Interface builder you only have to take the inner content before return part and rename that view with your outlet name inside viewDidLoad.

Comment: I added an extra function at the end which will help you to link your outlet, check my answer again at the end with this title: StoryBoard/InterfaceBuilder

Comment: Check it again, I modified a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much Mussa. You are the best.

Comment: My pleasure, Happy Coding :)